# How can I modify the error response for dto in NestJs?

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have created a NestJs app having a few APIs.I need to modify the format of the error response.

Using an interceptor I was able to intercept the successful response and standardize as per my liking similar to the below format.

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "data": [],
  "message": "Error",
  "errors": []
}
```

However the format returned when the dto validation fails is as mentioned below.

```
{
  "statusCode": 400,
  "message": [
    "status must be one of the following values: Pending"
  ],
  "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

How do I modify the error format as well similar to the above success response format?
I have the below code but it does not seem to be returning all the fields.

```
import {
    Injectable,
    NestInterceptor,
    ExecutionContext,
    BadGatewayException,
    CallHandler,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

export interface Response<T> {
    statusCode: number;
    message: string;
    errors: T;
    data: [];
  }

@Injectable()
export class ErrorsInterceptor<T> implements NestInterceptor<T, Response<T>> {
    intercept(context: ExecutionContext, next: CallHandler): Observable<Response<T>> {
        return next
            .handle()
            .pipe(
                map((response) => ({
                    statusCode: context.switchToHttp().getResponse().statusCode,
                    errors: response.errors,
                    message: response.message,
                    data: []
                })),
            );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using the standard NestJS [`ValidationPipe`](https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes#the-built-in-validationpipe) here. When a request fails DTO validation, `ValidationPipe` will throw an exception. This is then caught by Nest's [**exception filter**](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1), which grabs the response from the HTTP adapter, adds data from the caught exception, then returns it.

What you probably want to do is specify a custom `exceptionFactory` when you connect your `ValidationPipe` to Nest (usually in `main.ts`, wherever the main Nest app is being instantiated). There, you can apply whatever transforms you want and throw a custom error object.

It sounds like you've created your own exception filter, but without seeing the underlying object I can't say exactly how your error should look, but if you have a custom filter that's handling different types of exceptions like [here](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#catch-everything), you could create a custom exception, have your `exceptionFactory` create an instance of it, then handling it explicitly in your filter. So something like this

```ts
class DtoValidationError {
    validationErrors: ValidationError[];
    
    constructor(errors) {
        this.validationErrors = errors;
    }
}
```

```ts
app.useGlobalPipes(
    new ValidationPipe({
        exceptionFactory: (classValidatorErrors: ValidationError[]) => new DtoValidationError(classValidatorErrors)
    })
);
```

then, somewhere in your exception filter, handle those errors

```ts
if (exception instanceof DtoValidationError) {
    ... transform errors into desired structure ...
}
```